# cv has no member BackgroundSubtractorMOG

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv and followed instructions to install it as described here:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation
I used the section "Installation by Making Your Own Libraries from the Source Files", which worked well (using Visual Studio 2013). I am able to run basic commands, like read an image, write an image, run edge detection, video processing etc. 
But now I tried to use BackgroundSubtractorMOG and I get the error that BackgroundSubtractorMOG is not a member of cv. The simplest code is below and I don't know where to start. Am I missing something in my installation? Any ideas?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG bg;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you using opencv3.0 ?

Comment: I used git pull from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv, actually I don't know which version is on the master. Should I have pulled something else?

Comment: `git branch` will tell you, and 'master' (3.0) is the default, when you pull from github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with opencv3.0, BackgroundSubtractorMOG was moved to the [opencv_contrib repo](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/)

to use the remaining BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 or BackgroundSubtractorKNN you'd have to use:

```
Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> bgm = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to include the header

```
#include <background_segm.hpp>
```

Reference: http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG.html

path to the header file could be: **/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp**

Comment: opencv.hpp includes video.hpp, which includes background_segm.hpp, so that's not the reason. I confirmed it by adding the include you suggested, which did not help.

Comment: okay.. it usually happens and there is a lack of proper documentation for OpenCV.