# error: 'QRCodeDetector' is not a member of 'cv'

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use the opencv `QRCodeDetector` class in one of my functions, but unfortunately I am getting an error.
The error is saying that `QRCodeDetector` is not a member of `cv`.

C++ function code (test_qr.cpp):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void qrCheck(std::vector<std::string>& qrStorage, cv::Mat imageLeft_t0) {
    
    cv::QRCodeDetector qrDecoder = cv::QRCodeDetector(); // Error on this line

    std::string data = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(imageLeft_t0);

    if (data.length() > 0) {
        std::cout << "QR Decoded Data: " << data << std::endl;
        qrStorage.push_back(data);
    } else
        std::cout << "QR Code Not Detected" << std::endl;
}
```

In case you want to see my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project( DisplayImage )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable( DisplayImage test_qr.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I also tried doing something similar to this: [‘BackgroundSubtractorMOG’ is not a member of ‘cv’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493710/backgroundsubtractormog-is-not-a-member-of-cv)
But it didn't help.

Comment: Can't reprocude on Windows 10, Visual Studio Professional 2019, OpenCV 4.5.0 (pre-built DLLs from www.opencv.org). Can you please provide the whole stacktrace?

Comment: The error occurs during compilation. This is also on Unix and I am using OpenCV version 3.4.6